# Why is this directive in angularjs not accepting arguments despite following tutorials

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<html ng-app="calApp">

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var app = angular.module("calApp", []);

        app.controller('calController', function calController(){});

        app.directive('calendar',function(){
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                scope:{
                    friend: '='
                },
                template:"<h1>{{friend}}</h1>",
                controller: function($scope){
                    console.log($scope.friend);
                    console.log("hi");
                }
            }

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="calController">
    <calendar friend="Bob"></calendar>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm expecting "Bob" (or whatever is written in place of it) to be logged to the console and displayed in bold on the page. Instead, `undefined` is logged to the console and nothing is displayed on the page.

Does anybody know where I'm going wrong?

Part of me feels like it's something very simple, but I can't seem to figure out what that something is.

Comment: Yes, it is just the problem in defining the scope, that whether you are binding a `variable` or a `string` or a `function`. :)

Comment: "=" eval Bob to $scope.Bob which is undefined.. use "@" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need to change this

```
friend: '='
```

to this

```
friend: '@'
```

'=' is for variables (2 way data binding) and '@' for strings

Also with  this

```
friend: '='
```

you could do this

```
<calendar friend="'Bob'"></calendar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following snippet, check the console.log.

```js
        var app = angular.module("calApp", []);

        app.controller('calController', function calController(){});

        app.directive('calendar',function(){
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                scope:{
                    friend: '@'
                },
                template:"<h1>{{friend}}</h1>",
                controller: function($scope){
                    console.log($scope.friend);
                    console.log("hi");
                }
            }

        });
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
   <body ng-controller="calController" ng-app="calApp">
    <calendar friend="Bob"></calendar>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
            scope:{
                friend: '@'
            },
```

`=` is used when you are binding a variable